# Is there any crypto that are directly linked (pegged) to a real physical commodity like gold?

Tags: transactions, storage

Is there any crypto that are directly linked (pegged) to a real physical commodity like gold. Actual commodity held in actual real world storage somewhere.

Comment: this question is difficult to understand and needs more focus. please re-word and edit it

Comment: ETH and most currencies aren't backed by anyone. Its value is derived from the free market by people buying a selling. PAXG is one of many tokens backed by gold reserves.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any crypto that are directly linked (pegged) to a real physical commodity like gold.

There is [XAUt](https://support.bitfinex.com/hc/en-us/articles/900000136883-TETHER-XAUt-Token) from Tether.

> When we purchase ETH, who is held accountable for that money?[ Broker (Coinbase/Binance) or Ethereum] Is there any real world storage facilities that store that money?

This is a different question. Can you open a new question and ask only one question per submission, so StackExchange stays manageable.